# IronPython import package failing

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

So I've got a class that inherits from another class (called AbstractAbility). For some reason, I can't import it using

```
import Abstracts.AbstractAbility
```

Even though I have an init.py (properly named, but SO won't let me do the __ around it) in each folder.

My folder structure goes like this:

- Abilities

  - **init**.py
  - Abstracts

    - **init**.py
    - AbstractAbility
  - PoisonDebuff.py

Yet PoisonDebuff cannot access AbstractAbility.

Answer (score 0):

Try `from Abstracts.AbstractAbility import AbstractAbility`

Comment: Doing this causes an ImportException, with the message "No module named Abstracts.AbstractAbility"

Answer (score 0):

Think I got it. Visual Studio wasn't copying the init files over to the working directory. Now I have a different problem.